# wxPython button event shows inconsistent result in Windows & Linux

Tags: python, wxpython

I am a new programmer developing application in wxPython/Python. I am getting inconsistent result from a button event as follows.

```
def OnButton1Button(self, event):

    self.textCtrl9.AppendText(" 1st instance\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    self.textCtrl9.AppendText(" 2nd instance\n")
```

It should print `1st instance` and then after 5 seconds delay again print `2nd instance`. This is working fine in Windows OS but in Linux I am getting both `1st instance` & `2nd instance` at a time(simultaneously) after a 5 seconds delay of pressing the button.

I am really confused. Could anyone please suggest me some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a `self.textCtrl9.Update()` before the `sleep()` ?

Comment: `wx.Yield()` before the sleep should make the first append do its thing. Unfortunately I can't explain the differing behaviours though. Btw I think the expected behaviour is that they're both processed at the end (it's not synchronous, actions get queued up for the apps MainLoop to process and the sleep is blocking, thus stopping any events getting processed - which is why the app wont respond for that sleep 5) Maybe wx is able to offload some of the work to windows which processes it while your app is blocking - just a guess though

Comment: @ kraymer -self.textCtrl9.Update() doesn't solve the problem ... But wx.Yield() solves the problem. Thanks kraymer & GP89

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do?  Although wx.Yield() might work, you generally don't want to use time.sleep() in the event handlers in a GUI, since this can stop the main thread.  That is, is your main goal to update the GUI after 5 seconds, or is it to block the GUI's response to other inputs for the 5 seconds.  Either way, it would be better to not do it with sleep.

Answer (score 1):

This should be done using a **`wx.Timer`**.

Assuming that your primary goal is to update the GUI after 5 seconds, put the second `AppendText` in a function and set it to be called with wx.Timer.  This way, your GUI will still be responsive during the 5 second delay.

Putting calls to `time.sleep()` in an event handler in the GUI, and therefore in the main thread, will cause you no end of headaches.

On the other hand, if you really want your GUI to be unresponsive for the 5 seconds, you should do this explicitly, say using `Enable(False)` with the Window, and again, call `Enable(True)` using a timer when the 5 seconds are up.  This way, it will be indicated to the user that the GUI is inactive.